# What compounds give two products on reacting with NH2OH?

Tags: stereochemistry

This is a question from the chapter stereochemistry of my coaching module. The answer options include CH3CHO, DCHO, etc. How do I do this? I have an idea that if we take a racemic mixture of D and L isomers it is possible to get such products. Am I right? And is it possible? How do I do this question?

Comment: The oximes formed are not d/l, but E/Z so any assymmetric carbonyl compound will give rise to 2  products, DCHO for example will give 2 oximes while acetone will not.

Comment: @Waylander actually my book hasn't covered formation of oximes, it has only coveredmain definitions in stereochemistry like e/z, I'm not exactly sure what an oxime is, is there another way to get this answer?

Comment: Google "oxime formation". There is a good video explanation from the Khan Academy